# Spaces inserted in browser in <pre> with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, browser, haml

A simple test case:

`<% content = "<pre>a\nb</pre>" %>
<%= raw content %>`

Browser Screenshot, with inserted spaces on second line:

[image]

Here's where it gets interesting. In rails:

`raw(content).size # => 14 (correct)`

But, in JS:

`$("pre").html().length // => 13 (should be 3)`

Comment: Any chance you are using HAML for your layout?  If so, that would explain it as HAML will indent things for you.  Try rendering just the above without any layout at all.

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom Bingo! I am using HAML, and using `render layout: false` adds no spaces. Do I have to use the [ugly method](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Options.html#ugly-instance_method)?

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom or can I somehow disable indentation for a piece?

Comment: You might try http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#tilde

Comment: Awesome! If you put this as the answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any chance you are using HAML for your layout? If so, that would explain it as HAML will indent things for you. You can use HAML's `~` to get around this.

See: http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#tilde